# Repeating earlier stages in bamboo while a later longer running stage continues

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-deployment

Does Bamboo support the following?

The reading I've done discussed using agents to split up a slow running job and not this 'fast feedback' approach. The advantage over the typical approach that runs all stages once an executor is available is that all revisions get some level of testing, rather than just the last committed version before the executor became free.

Stage 1 = build stage
Stage 2 = unit test stage (5 minutes)
Stage 3 = integration test stage (1 hour)

STEPS
commit, revision 1
1 starts and passes
2 starts...
commit, r2
1 starts and passes
2 continues (55 minutes) left
commit, r3
1 starts and fails // provides early feedback, before integration testing is complete
2 continues
(repeat unit test cycle several times)
2 completes and passes, confirming that reversion 1 can be deployed
2 starts again for the latest stage 1 that passed (which is either revision 2 or one that passed unit testing in a later build and test cycle)

---

Unit and integration testing could be either separate stages or jobs, whichever supports this approach.

Comment: We use most of the Atlassian stack except Bamboo. That said, Jenkins (Hudson) will support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to enable concurrent builds in Bamboo: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+concurrent+builds
This means that the same plan will be run on commit #2 even if the run on commit #1 isn't finished yet. However you need to have enough free agents to run builds in this way.